# A riddle for the highway

Tags: riddle, word

I'm laying on the highway, but you can't drive over me, for as soon as you're over me, I'm over you.

What am I?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you are

> a shadow.

Because

> When you drive on a shadow, the shadow of the object will be on top of your car

Comment: But can't you drive on the shadow of your own car at noon?

Comment: @DudeWhoWantsToLearn i think you often drive on the shadow of your car, but an existing shadow across the highway (of a pole for instance), will appear to go over your car